# Update document with slice of structs

Tags: mongodb, go

Trying to update a document in MongoDB using the official mongo driver,go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo

this is my struct that I want to update

```
type Activity struct {
    Timestamp    time.Time          `bson:"timestamp,omitempty"`
    Type         string             `bson:"type,omitempty"`
}

type Member struct {
    ID           primitive.ObjectID `bson:"_id,omitempty"`
    Name         string             `bson:"name,omitempty"`
    Activities []Activity           `bson:"activities ,omitempty"`
}
```

this is the code for updating document

```
filter := bson.M{"_id": m.ID}
update := bson.M{
    "$set": bson.M{
        "name":        m.Name,
    },
    "$each": bson.M{"activities": m.Activities },
}

res, err := coll.UpdateOne(ctx, filter, update)
```

the name gets updated but nothing happens with the activities

what am I doing wrong? should I use ReplaceOne instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the name gets updated but nothing happens with the activities

This is because [$each](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/each/) array update operator is designed to be used with [$addToSet](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/#up._S_addToSe) (append unique) or [$push](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/#up._S_push)(append).

For example, if you would like to update the array with no duplicate activities the set:

```
update := bson.M{
    "$set": bson.M{
        "name": obj.Name,
    },
    "$addToSet": bson.M{"activities": bson.M{"$each": obj.Activities }},
}
cursor, err := collection.UpdateOne(context.Background(), filter, update )
```

Comment: Great, thank you! Works like a charm. Would you anyhow consider using ReplaceOne if I always want to update everything in the document?

Comment: Yes, ReplaceOne is better if you want to override the content of a document. This saves you the set/unset operations.